# android get time as int from countdowntimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am fresh in android programming and trying to find out countdowtimer. I need to get how many seconds are there for finishing as an integer because of determining the points of my simple quiz game. I have tried a lot however could not get an exact solution. Is there anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:----

```
TextView textic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

CountDownTimer count = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textic.setText("Seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        textic.setText("Finished");
    }
};

count.start();
```

For more info have a look at [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: that's true i have displayed how many seconds are there but i am trying to make it integer for scores. for example if there is 5 seconds to end the user has to get 5 points. score = score + xx however what should i write instead of xx

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
CountDownTimer count = new CountDownTimer(1000000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
        int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
        int hours = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60))%60;

        textic.setText(hours +":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        textic.setText("Finished");
    }
};

count.start();
```